# Regex - capturing incremental numbers between curly braces

Tags: java, regex

I have a piece of code that tries to repeatedly match a pattern with an incremented index inside a loop:

```
for(int count = 0; count < args.length; count++) {
        message.replaceFirst("^\\{" + count + "\\d}$", args[count]);
    }
```

What I want to be able to do is replace occurrences of {0}, {1} and so on in the message string with those in args. But try as I might, I simply cannot get the pattern to match. I am no regex expert, but I have tried a variety of regex combinations based on other questions here. I also tried using the replace method in StringUtils to no avail. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a regex at all. You know your search string beforehand and it is constant (i.e. you can build it from constant strings plus variable `count`) and thus there is no need to incorporate regular expressions.

Comment: Right, so I also tried `StringUtils.replace(message, "{" + count + "}", args[0]);` but that didn't work either.

Comment: You'll have to assign it to your variable afterwards, i.e. `message = StringUtils.replace(...);`.

Comment: Dang Strings are immutable, awful silly of me to forget that. That did the trick, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `^` and `$` characters are anchors.  They match the beginning and end of the string.  That expression will only match if the entire String is nothing but `{\\d}`.  I don't think they need to be there at all.

Also, Strings are immutable in java, the correct usage would be `message = message.replaceAll(blah);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
String pattern = "^\\{\\d+\\}$";
```

Explanation:

1. From the start of the string get a `{`
2. Then get as many digits as possible
3. Until a `}` is reached in the end of the string

Example:

```
String s = "{12}";
String pattern = "^\\{\\d+\\}$";
String s2 = s.replaceFirst(pattern, "9");

System.out.println(s2);
```

Outputs:

```
9
```

This should be fairly easy to apply to your code.

Comment: Surely `\\d+` rather than `\\d*`? We (probably) don't want to match `{}`.